# Socket.emit isn't working but socket.broadcast does

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

For some reason socket.emit isn't running don't know where the error is. However socket.broadcast works.

```
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { // on on client connection
        socket.on('login', function (uname, pword, email) { // on event login
            SetupPlayer(socket);
        });
    });
```

Here is the function called

```
var SetupPlayer= function(socket){
    GetPlayer(socket, function(PlayerObj){
        GetQuests(socket, function(QuestObj){
            socket.room = PlayerObj.RoomID;
            socket.emit('PlayerStructure', PlayerObj, QuestObj); // notify other clients about new player also passing players daya using set data structure
            socket.broadcast.in(socket.room).emit('AddPlayer', activeusers[socket.room][socket.id]); // same as above
        });
    });  
}
```

However, nothing happens on `socket.emit` but `socket.broadcast.in(socket.room).emit` does run

This is the clients code but don't think this is the problem.

```
socket.on('AddPlayer', function(playerstructure) {
    console.log(playerstructure);
});
socket.on('PlayerStructure', function(playerstructure) {
    console.log(playerstructure);
});
```

Comment: Was the connection established successfully?

Comment: Yes a connection was made and the broadcast emit works but the socket.emit doesnt